# dynamically calling liquid commands

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to call the metafields of an array of value by "injecting" it into the command, is something like this possible? I have tried the below but it will not return a value.

Also, i have noted that i would require the page to be reloaded when a variant is selected is this possible?

```
{% assign main_dimensions = "width_cm, height_cm, depth_cm, length_cm" | split: ','%}
{% assign main_dimensions_title = "Width (cm), Height (cm), Depth (cm), Length(cm)" | split: ','%}

{% for i in main_dimensions %}
{{ main_dimensions_title[1]}} - {{ product.metafields.global.main_dimensions[1].value }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, is not clear the problem with your code. What is the expected result? Regarding the second question: yes, liquid is a server-side language. You need to use javascript to achieve that.

Comment: You need to try this like `{% for i in main_dimensions %}
{{ main_dimensions_title[i]}} - {{ product.metafields.global.main_dimensions[i].value }} 
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Hi Onkar, That was my understanding also, unfortunately, this does not render any results

Hi Fabio, for the first loop i am hoping to pull the result from product.metafields.global.width_cm.value and then from product.metafields.global.height_cm.value or so on.

Answer (score 0):

After replicating the same on my dev store, I found some weired that need to be removed then It will worked as desired.

```
{% assign main_dimensions = "width_cm, height_cm, depth_cm, length_cm" | split: ',' %}
{% assign main_dimensions_title = "Width (cm), Height (cm), Depth (cm), Length(cm)" | split: ',' %}

{% for i in main_dimensions %}
// when split it it adding the space infront of second element due to space before , in to string
{% assign key = i | remove: ' ' %}
{{ main_dimensions_title[forloop.index0]}} - {{ product.metafields.global.main_dimensions[key].value }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

so use remove to eliminate it or simply create the string like this bellow without spaces.

```
{% assign main_dimensions = "width_cm,height_cm,depth_cm,length_cm" | split: ',' %}
{% assign main_dimensions_title = "Width (cm), Height (cm), Depth (cm), Length(cm)" | split: ',' %}

{{ product.metafields.global | json }}<br/>

{% for i in main_dimensions %}
{{ main_dimensions_title[forloop.index0]}} - {{ product.metafields.global.main_dimensions[i].value }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```